# Rate limiting with redis

Tags: redis, rate-limiting, redisson

I'm using elasticache redis for rate limit and use Redisson as the client, the related code is:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Long>> incrementSingleKeys(
      List<String> keys, List<Long> increments, List<Long> ttls) {

    RBatch batch = redissonClient.createBatch(BatchOptions.defaults());

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
      batch.getAtomicLong(keys.get(i)).addAndGetAsync(increments.get(i));
    }
    return batch
        .executeAsync()
        .thenCompose(
            (counters) -> {
              List<String> keysToSet = Lists.newArrayList();
              List<Long> TTLsToSet = Lists.newArrayList();
              for (int i = 0; i < counters.size(); i++) {
                if (counters.get(i) == increments.get(i)) { // only set ttl for new keys
                  keysToSet.add(keys.get(i));
                  TTLsToSet.add(ttls.get(i));
                }
              }
              if (!keysToSet.isEmpty()) { // Call setTTLS
                return setTTLs(keysToSet, TTLsToSet)
                    .thenApply(
                        (r) -> counters
                    );
              } else {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(counters);
              }
            });
  }

public CompletableFuture<List<Boolean>> setTTLs(List<String> keys, List<Long> TTLs) {
    CompletableFuture<List<Boolean>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    RBatch batch = redissonClient.createBatch(BatchOptions.defaults());
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
      batch.getBucket(keys.get(i)).expireAsync(TTLs.get(i), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    batch
        .executeAsync()
        .whenComplete(
            (list, ex) -> {
              if (ex != null) {
                future.complete(
                    Collections.nCopies(size, false);  // fail open
                )
              } else {
                future.complete(
                    list.stream()
                        .map(entry -> (entry instanceof Boolean ? (Boolean) entry : false))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                );
              }
            });
    return future;
}
```

Basically, I'll set ttl only for new keys. The issue is that sometimes the increment batch call is successful but setTTL call timeout, which results in a permanent key and could lead to incorrect rate limiting. One workaround is to always get and set ttl whenever increment happens, but this would affect the performance. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Could you share source code of `setTTLs` method?

Comment: Added the source code.

Comment: Did you try to follow this topic https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/16.-FAQ#q-i-saw-a-redistimeoutexception-what-does-it-mean-what-shall-i-do-can-redisson-team-fix-it

Comment: It did help but due to networking latency spike, timeout can still happen. I did some further research and find there's no transaction mechanism in redis, so I'll just call setTTL every time.

Comment: try to use RBatch with ExecutionMode.IN_MEMORY_ATOMIC or ExecutionMode.REDIS_WRITE_ATOMIC option to achive transaction.